# Passing querystring with HyperLinkField

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, query-string

I have a gridview where one column is going to be a hyperlink that will open a new browswer window and display a file so upon clicking this link I am currently using the NavigateUrl and calling a new page and setting the target to blank.  My problem is that in this new page I will need to know the ID of the row that was selected.  How can I pass this information? Querystring doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out HyperLinkField's NavigateUrlFormatString property [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlformatstring.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using NaviagteURL use a click event, add a session variable, and response redirect to the page. Look for it in the page load on the new page.

Comment: I am using a HyperLinkField so there is no onclick

Comment: Session - brrrr. Who knows how long the client would be looking at the list before clicking? Who knows how long the list would be? Better to format url's so they're 'self-contains' on the client just waiting to be clicked. No harm if they're not. Keeps the server out of the redirection.